# How to define optional parameters in Java Script

Tags: javascript, optional-parameters

Here is my object construction,

```
function Employee(name, dob) {
       this.Name = name;
       this.DateOfBirth = new Date(dob);
   }
```

Now, I have created an instance for this, like

```
var emp = new Employee("sample","12/12/12");
```

Its working fine when i print the output.

But, if i create the object like

```
var emp = new Employee(name = "sample");
```

or

```
var emp = new Employee(dob = "12/12/12");
```

its not working fine. In both the cases, the `DateOfBirth` field is invalid.

I need to define an object with optional parameters.

Comment: You can pass and then read an object to the constructor; `new Employee({name: "bob", age: 40});`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript does not support named optional parameters.

When you do `var emp = new Employee(name = "sample");`

You're declaring a `name` global variable, assigning `sample` to it and passing *that* to the `new` call.

You can use objects to accomplish similar syntax in JS:

```
var emp = new Employee({name:"sample"});
```

Where the Employee function becomes:

```
function Employee(options) {
       this.Name = options.name;
       if(options.dob !== undefined){
           this.DateOfBirth = new Date(options.dob);
       }
}
```

Worth mentioning, in practice, you often don't need an Employee class, and can simply do:

```
var emp = {name:"sample"};
```

Or:

```
var emp = {dob:new Date("12/12/12");}
```

So unless Employee grows to become a real model (and has more than just two fields) I think that you might want to consider that.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Employee(params) {
    if (typeof params != "undefined") {
        this.Name = (typeof params.name != "undefined") ? params.name : "";
        this.DateOfBirth = (typeof params.dob != "undefined") ? new Date(params.dob) : null;
    }
}

new Employee({
    name: "John",
    dob: "12/12/12"
});
new Employee({
    name: "John"
});
new Employee({
    dob: "12/12/12"
});
```

or using simple statements using `||`.

```
function Employee(params) {
    params = params || {};
    this.Name = params.name || "";
    this.DateOfBirth = new Date(params.dob || "");
}
```

Comment: `typeof` is an operator, not a function. Please consider `typeof name !== "undefined"` . Also, I think there is a big difference between setting default values (like the empty string in your case) and keeping the values `undefined`. Last thing, your first example does not work (You're setting to `null` but checking against `undefined` which are completely different), please consider revising those things.

Answer (score -1):

As a good practice, you should never leave out variables.
You can explicitly call `var emp = new Employee(null, "12/12/12");`

This way everything is initialized and you will not havea headaches later on.
There is also something like this, but you really need to check the values before assigning.

```
function Employee() {
       this.Name = name;
       this.DateOfBirth = new Date(dob);
   }

var emp = new Employee(name = null,dob = "12/12/12");
```

Comment: **You're defining two globals here!** You're making a `name` global and a `dob` global. Also OP wanted a clear syntax. Also, in JavaScript, null and undefined do _not_ mean the same thing.

Comment: yep...you're right. Sorry about that. I'm just gettin to understand how the variables actually work in js